# Laravel schedule works but command not working

Tags: laravel, command, schedule

With laravel schedule I have problem. schedule runs but command not working. here is example.I send mail from schedule on every minute and also want to run command on every minute to test it. command not working. I did't get email from command(with text "command executed").What I am doing wrong?
Please help.

Kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\myCustomCommand'
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {

        //this works
        sendMailFunction('someone@gmail.com', 'test mail', 'schedule executed'); 

        //this is not working
        $schedule->command('command:myCustomCommand')->cron('* * * * *')
    }

}
```

Command

```
class myCustomCommand extends Command {


    protected $name = 'command:myCustomCommand';


    protected $description = 'some description';


    public function handle() {
        sendMailFunction('someone@gmail.com', 'test mail', 'command executed');
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should test yout command from command line first? What error does it return?

Comment: there are no errors. from command line it works. i think cron() function is not works. I also tried everyMinute() but still no result. I have no idea why it not works

Comment: Did you run this on your server: `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to enable Laravel scheduler?

Comment: yes scheduler working. because I got emails from schedule in every minute with text "schedule executed"

Comment: Well, it's really strange. Are there any schedule or sending mails related errors in `/storage/laravel.log`?

Comment: Also maybe you want to try to stop cron and rerun it so it output errors and messages into some log file, like `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /home/sched.log 2>&1` and after that use `try...catch` constructure to output any catched exceptions.

Comment: Oh yes. I found reason. In logs I have error "exec() has been disabled for security reasons". Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It may seemed the schedule works, but actually not. Refer to [laravel cannot run scheduled command, while queue:listen run schedule() periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47548220/6521116)

Comment: did you checked your php artisan list? to see if your command "command:myCustomCommand" exist  or not!!

Answer (score 0):

in localhost :`php artisan schedule:run`

in host :`* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

You have to see what it is
or
Introduce your controller in kernel.php