# laravel cannot run scheduled command, while queue:listen run schedule() periodically

Tags: php, laravel, command, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

***Note: My question has nothing to do with [Command schedule in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47513845/6521116) which schedule not work. But in my question the scheduling works, but it cannot call the artisan command.***

I use laravel scheduling artisan command. I run the command directly from the console like this `sudo -u www-data /var/www/market/artisan command:printer-serving 281H28`.

I know it works because, I've `Log::info('Working')` at the entry of the `handle()` function of the command.

While when I use laravel's scheduling. And the cron works well, for below `Log::info('command:printer-serving 281H28');` output the content to the console continuously.

**But the artisan command not executed, it output nothing to the console, and not write something to the DB**

In the Kernel.php

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Log;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
        'App\Console\Commands\CommandPrinterServing',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
        Log::info('command:printer-serving 281H28');
        $schedule->command('command:printer-serving --force 281H28')->everyMinute();
        //$schedule->command('printer-serving')->everyMinute();
        //$schedule->command(CommandPrinterServing::class, ['281H28'])->everyMinute();
    }

}
```

Command name, `protected $signature = 'command:printer-serving {pid}';`

**Note**
No matter what string even not a command I put in `$schedule->command()` function, nothing will changes and not a error reported from the cron log or laravel log.

I want to know how to debug the  `$schedule->command()` function.

---

Cron file `vi /etc/cron.minutely/printer-task-minute`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/market
sudo -u www-data ./artisan command:regen-htaccess
#sudo -u www-data ./artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
sudo -u www-data ./artisan schedule:run
```

The weired thing is log output four thmes every 3 seconds.

```
> [2017-11-29 16:52:14] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:14] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:14] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:14] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:17] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:17] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:17] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:17] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:21] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:21] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:21] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:21] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28 
> [2017-11-29 16:52:24] worker_env.INFO: command:printer-serving 281H28
```

I'm puzzled about the log frequency, so I stop cron and beanstalkd. But the log output doesn't stop. Even I stop apache2, the log keeping output. Then I check the php process, and find there are four `queue:listen --queue=xxxx --env=worker_env --delay=3` in the output of command `ps aux | grep php`. Here I found why the log output in that frequency, but I don't know why `queue:listen` execute the `schedule()` function as this question [Understanding Queues and Scheduler on Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36625969/6521116).

---

Each time I executed a artisan command `sudo -u www-data /var/www/market/artisan xxxxx` the `schedule()` function will be called one time. And if the command is `queue:listen` like `sudo -u www-data /var/www/market/artisan queue:listen xxxxx` the `schedule()` function will be called periodically. But the command in the `schedule()` will not run, except the `Log::info()`. Only when run `schedule:run` command, both the artisan command and `Log::info()` in `schedule()` will executed.

Comment: can you create another command which does the same task but without any space between the words

Comment: I've modify the command, and use default parameter in the command. Then use `$schedule->command('command:printer_serving')->everyMinute();
`, but it also not works.

Comment: is it working directly , like php artisan printer_serving

Comment: Yes, it works well.

Comment: is this the only cron job that is failing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command schedule in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513845/command-schedule-in-laravel)

Comment: what is the name of the command?

Comment: @Troyer, read my question once more. The command in my question not run which is different with that one.

Comment: @DhavalChheda I can run the command from the console, and I've add the commandname in the question.

Comment: Have u configured the cron setup in your server?

Comment: @DhavalChheda certainly, as the question say, the schedule works well. For the `Log` function in the Kernel.php output content to the console continuously.

Comment: Looks like the Cron configuration is executing the schedule every second, that's why you are getting a lot of registers inside the Log, you should put the Log::info inside the command because when the schedule function is called doesn't mean it will execute the commands.

Comment: Instead of `$schedule->command('command:printer-serving --force 281H28')->everyMinute();` try: 

`$schedule->exec(' sudo -u www-data -p password /var/www/market/artisan command:printer_serving 281H28')->everyMinute();`

Comment: @Troyer I have tried it, it not works. I also try this `$schedule->call(function(){Log::info('ssssssss');})->everyMinute();` without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It costs me a day to google the issue, read laravel docs, and run many test. Finally I make it out.

Laravel's `artisan queue:listen` command call the `schedule()` in the Kernel.php periodically, while it only run the `Log::info()` in the `schedule()` not the `$schedule->command()`(**Here I'm also confused**).

I've four queue running, for queue1 `sudo -u www-data php artisan queue:work --queue=queue1 --env=worker_env --delay=3 --timeout=600`. Same with queue2, 3, 4. So the `Log::info()` in the `schedule()` will executed four times every 3 seconds.

Above make me thought the schedule works well. Actually, the schedule is not executed. I found `/etc/cron.minutely/printer-task-minute` have no `x` privilege, so I add the `x` privilege for it. And I found I didn't config the crontab file, so I add `*  *    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.minutely )` to `/etc/crontab`(I'm not familar with cron).

**Solution:**
  Config the cron like above, or refer to the manual.
  Change `queue:listen` to `queue:work`(When changed to `queue:work`, `schedule()` will not executed by queue periodically, **I also don't know the reason here.**).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using the below command

```
$schedule->command('printer_serving')->everyMinute()‌​;
```

Comment: This not works for me. As the command name is `'command:printer-serving {pid}'`, and from the console I need to run `sudo -u www-data /var/www/market/artisan command:printer_serving 281H28`